# CardView em API 10

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Com de fundo normal:

[image: img fundo branco]

Ao trocar por outra cor é exibido uma **linha** em baixo do TextView: 
[image: img fundo preto]

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#18d018"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:lines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Titulo de exemplo"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Qual é o problema que você está tendo? É a linha que está apacendo na segunda imagem?

Comment: Sim, isto mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa definir o divisor como 0, para que não tenha essa linha em baixo de cada cardView, isso pode ser usado tanto para montar uma lista com os "cards", como também individualmente.

```
    <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#E6E6E6"
    android:dividerHeight="0px"/>
```

Comment: tentei e não funcionou